# Não consigo mostrar os dados da função "detalhes()" que criei

Tags: java, string, funções

Eu criei um programa sobre livros, como se fosse uma biblioteca. Então no final, minha intenção seria mostrar o nome do livro, quem está lendo, total de páginas, etc.
Criei todas as funções, mas ao tentar mostrar os dados como string na função detalhes() não dá certo.
O código abaixo mostra o que eu tentei fazer, coloquei só o titulo do livro para ficar fácil de compreender. Nenhum desses dois códigos funcionou, procurei algumas perguntas sobre isso mas não encontrei.

```
public String detalhes() {
        return "Livro: " + tituloLivro;
    }
```

```
public void detalhes() {
        System.out.println("Livro: " + tituloLivro);
    }
```

Answer (score -3):

Vc tem que passar o parâmetro do titulo do livro para quem chama a função, se não como a sua função vai saber qual titulo do livro é?

```
public String detalhes(string tituloLivro) {
    return "Livro: " + tituloLivro;
}
```